# C++ getting error C2440

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Hello I'm using Visual Studio c++ 2010

I'm having a problem with this code ( it's taken from C language code ) :

```
MEMBLOCK* create_memblock (HANDLE hProc,  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION *meminfo)
{

    MEMBLOCK *mb = malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));

    if (mb)
    {
        mb->hProc = hProc;
        mb->addr = meminfo->BaseAddress;
        mb->size = meminfo->RegionSize;
        mb->buffer = malloc(meminfo->RegionSize);
        mb->next = NULL;

    }
    return mb;
}
```

I'm having these errors :

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'MEMBLOCK *'          
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'PVOID' to 'unsigned char *'    
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char *'
```

I'm kinda newbie. Can you please provide a converted code for this that actually works with c++.

Thank you

Comment: If you're trying to compile C code, use a C compiler.

Comment: malloc return `void*` you need to explicitly cast to `MEMBLOCK*`. Like this `MEMBLOCK *mb = (MEMBLOCK*)malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));` or better `MEMBLOCK *mb = static_cast<MEMBLOCK*>(malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK)));`

Comment: `MEMBLOCK *mb = (MEMBLOCK*)malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));` or `/TC` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ You may not assign a pointer of type `void *` to a pointer of some other type. So for example instead of writing

```
MEMBLOCK *mb = malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));
```

You have to write

```
MEMBLOCK *mb = ( MEMBLOCK * )malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));
```

Also you have to change other statements where there is the same problem. It seems these statements are

```
mb->addr = ( unsigned char * )meminfo->BaseAddress;
mb->buffer = ( unsigned char * )malloc(meminfo->RegionSize);
```

It is a good example of that you **always** should use an explicit casting even in C. That makes the code more safe and clear.

Comment: Casting `void *` in C is neither safer nor clearer, it's completely redundant. The only advantage is polyglottism.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're programming in C++, you should not use the old C function `malloc`. Instead I would recommend that you use the C++ `new` construct:

```
MEMBLOCK *mb = new MEMBLOCK;
```

Answer (score 2):

`malloc()` returns `void*`, and C++ does not automatically cast `void*` to a different pointer type. So you have to cast the return value:

```
MEMBLOCK *mb = (MEMBLOCK*) malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));
```

Try:

```
MEMBLOCK* create_memblock (HANDLE hProc,  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION *meminfo)
{
    MEMBLOCK *mb = (MEMBLOCK*)malloc(sizeof(MEMBLOCK));

    if (mb)
    {
        mb->hProc = hProc;
        mb->addr = meminfo->BaseAddress;
        mb->size = meminfo->RegionSize;
        mb->buffer = malloc(meminfo->RegionSize);
        mb->next = NULL;

    }
    return mb;
}
```

Comment: You may want to say *why* the OP have to cast the return. Because, as we all know, in C you [should not cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).